# Traducción del primer párrafo de "Billie Jean"

Tags: traducción, gramática, letras-de-canciones

Estuve traduciendo músicas para aprender inglés, y cuando empecé me di cuenta de que no tiene sentido mi traducción:

```
She said I am the one, who will dance on the floor in the round 
(ella dice yo soy el primero, quien deberia bailar en el suelo en la ronda)
```

vayamos por partes:

`She said I am the one`,traduje así: ella dice que soy el primero/mejor/uno?

`who will dance on the floor in the round`, en este caso no se qui significa "floor"

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que no tiene sentido? Nótese que las preguntas de este tipo deben venir acompañadas por explicaciones; de lo contrario, se consideran _peticiones de corrección_ y están fuera del ámbito del sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). Por tanto, dale a [edit] para incluri estos detalles. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Si lo que quieres es aprender inglés, te recomendamos que visites el _stack_ [English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) en este mismo sitio. Lo importante no es cómo traduzcas el texto, sino entenderlo correctamente, que te hagas una idea mental de lo que el autor quiso decir. Puedes preguntar allí y seguramente tendrás respuestas mucho mejores de las que te podamos dar nosotros. Además, como dice @fedorqui, necesitamos dudas concretas, y no simplemente una petición de corrección de un texto. ¡Anímate a concretar!

Comment: @fedorqui bueno edite mi pregunta, espero que la abran nuevamente.

Comment: @hubman Lamentablemente, creo que aún no reúne las condiciones para ser reabierta. Fíjate en lo que se indica en los motivos de cerrado por off-topic: _Questions asking for corrections in a text e.g. "are there any mistakes in this text?" are off-topic. You can ask specific sentences in separate questions that may help other users. For more information, see what you can ask [here](/help/on-topic)_. Dale una buena lectura y edita para que tu pregunta cubra esos extremos. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión debería ser:

> Ella era más como una reina de belleza en una película

El uso del like, puede ser como, por ejemplo, gustar, así también).

> Dije que esto no cuenta, pero qué quiere decir (ella) con
>   yo soy el primero que bailará en el ruedo del suelo.(?)
>   Y ella dijo que yo sería el primero quien bailará en el ruedo del suelo.

(Falta más contexto de la estrofa para poder interpretar bien. No traduzcas literal, porque nunca tendrá sentido una frase en inglés pasada al español, ya que tienen morfosintaxis diferentes.)

Comment: es la musica de michael jackson, billy jeans,